# how to get no of users created per month from a list of created-dates either in data frame or a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
  created Date:     
  01-04-2019,
  29-04-2019,
  25-04-2019,
  14-06-2019,
  14-06-2019,
  14-06-2019
```

I want the o/p like for 04th month 2 users and 06th month 3 users

Comment: Irrespective of dates how to achieve the above one?.....tq in adv

Answer (score 1):

Convert values by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then to months by [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['created Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.month.value_counts()
print (s)
6    3
4    3
Name: created Date, dtype: int64
```

If need new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = s.rename_axis('month').reset_index(name='counts')
print (df1)
   month  counts
0      6       3
1      4       3
```

For new column in original data use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['created Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.month
df['counts'] = s.groupby(s).transform('size')
print (df)
  created Date  counts
0   01-04-2019       3
1   29-04-2019       3
2   25-04-2019       3
3   14-06-2019       3
4   14-06-2019       3
5   14-06-2019       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Or try using a `groupby` call with `transform('size')`:

```
df['new'] = df['created Date'].dt.month
df['count'] = df.groupby('new')['new'].transform('size')
df = df.drop('new', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value_count()` to get your result:-

```
df['new'] = df['created Date'].dt.month
date_series = df['new'].value_counts()   # Counting users per month
date_dict = date_series.to_dict()    # Converting into dictionary.

for key,value in date_dict.items():   # Getting key and value.
    print(f"{key}  Month -->>\t {value} Users")
```

I hope it may help you.